# Display current user nickname with Backbone.js and Spring Security

Tags: javascript, spring, backbone.js, spring-security

Here is my project: [github](https://github.com/s1ddok/todosapp).
The folders you should look into are `-spring` and `-sharedresources`.

I've added login functionality to my app recently and now I want to display a current user nickname.

I've created a placeholder for now in navbar, which just says `sam` for now.

What are the ways to get current user info with Backbone and Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an REST endpoint that exposes your user's information. If you only need the username, then you can expose an endpoint that looks like:

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/users/self")
    public String self(Principal user) {
        return user == null ? null : user.getName();
    }
}
```

of course you can make this a bit fancier if you want to expose all the details about your user:

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/users/self")
    public Principal self(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Be careful of what properties are being written to the response as you don't want to expose the password of the user this way.

If you want to get more fancy you can use Spring Security's [`@AuthenticationPrincipal`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal)

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/users/self")
    public Principal self(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Be careful of what properties are being written to the response as you don't want to expose the password of the user this way.

Once you have exposed your user via a REST endpoint, you can call the endpoint to update your user information just as you normally would.

Comment: Thank's for such a detailed post, but I more or less know how to make it in java, i don't know what is the best practice for that in backbone with my project structure.